# Best Practice for Faking JSON Data Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Hi I am working on writing tests for a small API I have built with Laravel. I have data coming into the API via an axios post request on the front-end and I am faking the data with the following.

```
public function test_that_the_form_json_data_structure_is_correct() 
{
    $lead = [
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        'email' => 'johndoe@example.com',
        'phone' => '000-000-0000',
        'street_address' => '123 Main Street',
        'city' => 'CityA',
        'state' => 'ZZ',
        'zip' => '928171',
        'spouse' => [
            'name' => 'Sarah Aims',
            'email' => 'sarahaims@example.com',
            'phone' => '000-000-0000',
        ]
    ];
    $quote = [
        'address_is_same' => 1,
        'property_street' => '123 Main Street',
        'property_city' => 'CityA',
        'property_state' => 'ZZ',
        'property_zip' => '928171',
        'primary_residence' => 1,
        'secondary_residence' => 0,
        'rental_property' => 0,
        'number_of_units' => 2,
        'losses' => 0,
        'explain' => 'Some explaination here...',
        'additional_comments' => 'Additional comments here...'
    ];

    $this->json('POST', '/get-a-quote/home', [
        'data' => [
            'lead' => $lead,
            'quote' => $quote
        ]
    ])->seeJsonStructure([
        'lead_id',
        'quote_id'
    ]);
}
```

I am realizing that I will need to write that $lead array variable in multiple tests for different forms that I have on the front-end. I know that the model factories in Laravel are specifically for classes so I would like to know what best practice is for working with JSON data that isn't formatted like your models and how to best test this. I am thinking I will need to test the actually data going in which is what you see above and then write a test for the API on what it does with that incoming data ie. creating models etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your tests are just like your normal code base. DRY principle still applies.

So I wanted to recommend using Laravel [factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/seeding#using-model-factories) first. For example, I guess your `$lead` variable is a `User` model, in that case you could do :

`$lead = factory(User::class)->make()->toArray()`

And that would return a full `User` model as an array.

But you said :

> working with JSON data that isn't formatted like your models

So in that case, I'd simply have helpers in my tests. If you need to use this everywhere, you could even make a class with static methods that'd return data fully, and then you could change fields you need to change inside your tests.

Comment: Okay yea that’s what I was thinking. Creating helper classes with static methods. Right the data isn’t formatted the same.